# Add edge-weight to network .graphml

Tags: r, network-programming, igraph

I'm using different R packages to generate my network (vegan,bipartite,Hmisc,igraph). At the end, I import my network in .graphml format into Cytoscape 3.4.0. 
Then I select File>Import>Network>File.
I load the network, I can visualize it correctly, but when I want to see the edges weight, they are missing (in the edge table)... My goal is just to adjust the edges width according to their weight.

When I look at my graphml file in a text editor, it doesn't contain the edge-weights. Which means to me that there is a missing step in my R pipeline to add the edge values to the graphml file.

To sum up my pipeline

```
> mat=rcorr(as.matrix(g)) #g is my OTU table
> matp=mat$P
> vec=p.adjust(matp,method="fdr")
> matpa=matrix(vec,nrow=100,ncol=100)
> matpa[matpa>.01]=0 
> matr=mat$r
> matr[(-0.6)<matr& matr<0.6]=0
```

Combine the two tables to keep rho values with p-value<0.01 (matr2)

```
> matr2.c=as.matrix(matr2)
> net=graph.adjacency(matr2.c,weighted=T,mode="undirected",diag=F)
> net=delete.vertices(net,which(degree(net)<1))
```

And then I plot my graph, and everything is normal. I generate my graphml file this way

```
> write.graph(net,"net.graphml",format=c("graphml"))
```

I'm a beginner with R Studio, and I'm not really familiar with all the functions from the igraph package.I read the manual several times, but I'm still not sure about which function I should choose.

Thanks

Alice

Comment: To clarify, the `igraph` network looks okay but when written to `graphml` format it loses the edge weights?

Comment: Exactly. In some way, the edge weights do not follow when I generate the graphml file.

Comment: A very quick google found this (https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/graphml-format/) that describes that the edge weights are encoded in graphml format with an alias, in this case `d1`. You will need to share the graphml file for us to see, preferably a very small section.

Comment: Thank you! Here is one of my files shared on google doc [link] https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Sqb80iS3cvSm5UYThxQThVR3c/view?usp=sharing